# Forcing a cascade delete with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

I have a table which I need to delete from, but it has many foreign keys referencing it. I've never before used `ON DELETE CASCADE` - we have a kind of rule to soft delete records, or if a hard delete is absolutely required, to manually clean up any linked tables before/after deletion.

Is there a way, or a helper function somewhere, that will take a particular table (and record(s) in that table), iterate through every table/record in the database that is linked to it, and perform deletes. I want to believe for now that this isn't TOO bad a practice.

So, e.g. schema:

```
Organisations (OrganisationID, Name)

Users (UserID, FirstName, LastName, OrganisationID)
Projects (ProjectID, Name, OrganisationID)
Organisations_Markets (OrganisationID, MarketID)

Tasks (TaskID, Description, UserID)
```

If I wanted to delete where OrganisationID=3...

I know there's a way to list all the FKs in SQL - `EXEC sp_fkeys 'Organisations'`. How could I do this in EF, and do it for any nested FKs. So in the example above, the first deletes will be on the `Tasks` table (any records that are linked to `Users` where OrganisationID=3), and so on and so on.

edit: performance is not an issue - there'll never be more than 100 rows in total - so I'm happy to use EF for delete

Answer (score 1):

In your model, it seems there are standard one-to-many relationships between `Organization` and `Users` and between `Organization` and `Projects`.

So every `Organization` has zero or more `Users`; every `User` belongs to exactly one `Organization`

Similarly every `Organization` has zero or more 'Projects`, every`Project`belongs to exactly one`Organization`.

You also mention `Organisation_Markets`. You don't specify this, but it looks like a junction table for a many-to-many relation between `Organization` and `Market`: Every `Organization` refers to zero or more `Markets`; every `Market` refers to zero or more `Organizations`.

If you'd set-up the [one-to-many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) and [many-to-many](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) relationships following the [entity framework coding conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) you could safely remove an `Organization`.

Entity framework will automatically remove all `Users` and `Projects` from this `Organization`. All `Markets` that refer to this `Organization` won't refer to the deleted `Organization` anymore. But as it is allowed for a `Market` to refer to no `Organization` at all, `Markets` without `Organizations` won't be removed.

```
class Organization
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // Primary key
    // an Organization has zero or more Users (one-to-many):
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
    // an Organization has zero or more Projects (one-to-many):
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects {get; set;

    // an Organization refers to zero or more Markets (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Market> Markets {get; set;}
}

class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // Primary key
    // every User belongs to one Organization using foreign key
    public int OrganizationId {get; set;}
    public Organization Organization {get; set;}
}

class Project
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // Primary key
    // every Project belongs to one Organization using foreign key
    public int OrganizationId {get; set;}
    public Organization Organization {get; set;}
}

class Market
{
    public int Id {get; set;}    // Primary key
    // every Market refers to zero or more Organizations (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organizations {get; set;}
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations {get; set;}
    public DbSet<User> Users{get; set;}
    public DbSet<Project> Projects{get; set;}
    public DbSet<Market> Markets{get; set;}
}
```

That's all. Because I followed the entity framework coding conventions, entity framework will recognize the one-to-many and many-to-many relationships and create the proper foreign keys. It will even create the junction table needed for the many-to-many relation, even though I didn't mention it.

By the way, I don't need the junction table. If I want all Markets belonging to an Organization I use property `Organization.Markets`. Entity framework will know that a join with the junction table is needed and will create the proper SQL code for it.

If you don't want the defaults, for instance different table names, consider using [fluent-API](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx) or data annotations for this.

Now to remove an Organization do something like this:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    Organization organizationToRemove = dbContext.Organizations
        .Where(organization => ...)
        ... etc.
    dbContext.Organizations.Remove(organizationToRemove);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Entity framework will automatically update other tables

- All `Users` of the `Organization` are removed
- All `Projects` of the `Organization` are removed
- All references to the `Organization` in all `Markets` are removed.

So you don't need a special function to neatly clean up all references to the `Organization` you removed. Entity Framework will do this correctly for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Getting the `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint...` though (this project uses EF 6). I should add that I use DB-first not code-first. You may be correct here, but it's just not happening. If I figure it out I'll post an answer..